# Compare phone number from database in different condition

Tags: android, phone-number

I'm developing sms APP and want to receive sms from the specific numbers. But number can be changed sometime with country code as +923201234567 or sometime without country code 03201234567 how I can compare number from database? because don't know in which format number is saved in database(with country code or without country code)

```
public boolean isMember(String phone, long id){
    String query = "SELECT * from members where phone = ? AND active = 1 AND gid = ?";
    Cursor c = dbActions.rawQuery(query, new String[]{String.valueOf(phone), String.valueOf(id)});
    return c.moveToFirst();
}
```

Suppose if the number is saved in database without country code 03201234567 then my requirement is to get true if I compare it with country code. +923201234567. Country code could be changed.

`PhoneNumberUtils.compare();` is not useful because it not compare with database.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't acquire the correct information always; then you need to look into heuristics.

Meaning: you could write your own comparisons; and when you encounter two numbers like:

```
  03201234567
+923201234567
```

you can figure: their "tail" is equal; the only difference is that the first one starts with 0 (so no country code) and the second one with +92. So it might be reasonable to declare those two numbers to be equal.

So a "solution" would do things like "normalize" your input (remove all non-digit content; except for leading + signs); and to then make such "tail-bound" comparisons.

If that is "too" fuzzy; I guess then you should step back and describe the **requirement** that you actually try to resolve here. Why are you comparing numbers; and what do you intend to do with the output of that comparison?!

Comment: suppose I saved number in database in this format. `03201234567` then I received sms from this number `+923201234567` I want to test is it in database? because both are same by us. But in database it will say `false` did you understand my problem?

Comment: Yes. What I am saying is: you might have fetch **all** numbers from the database; and make such string comparisons. Or the other way round: you take the number that comes in via SMS; and you remove the area code from that string; and then you check if the "remainder" gives a hit in the database.

Comment: Getting all the number could solve my problem. But I don't know what area code length could be in other countries. Any how let me try with getting all number and loop through all to compare if any one match using the `PhoneNumberUtils.compare()`

Comment: Well, those country codes have a **maximum** length. You could always try to remove "+"  and then 1, 2, 3 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Normalize all of the phone numbers into the same format before you put them into the database.  That way you can just do a normal db search.

The other thing I've done for phone numbers is to convert all letters into the appropriate number, then remove all non digits, then just compare the last 7 digits.

Comment: I don't know what format will be used from the other countries, I'm trying to make it international base numbers.